# /media/ubuntu Fresh install?

Tags: system-installation

So I just installed Ubuntu, I set up my partition beforehand,a 150GB ext4. When I installed Ubuntu it asked me to drag a slider to set up the partition, so I left it in the middle. Files getting half and Ubuntu getting half. Well the install went well and now I have a /media/ubuntu mount that is empty.... Is it important and can/how do I get rid of it and give the whole partition to my files and not an empty mount. I am relatively new to Ubuntu so if any other info is needed please ask.

Comment: Questions about development version are offtopic here.You question is not an version dependent one.So change Ubuntu version in your question from 14.04 to 13.10.And take a screenshot of your gparted partition editor and upload that image to imgur.com.Finally post the uploaded link here.

Comment: http://imgur.com/fD7cOUH and @aveemashfaq

Comment: Did you want to delete /dev/sda7? I think you can't be able to delete that partition.

Comment: No, /dev/sda/5 is the random /media/ubuntu that is empty. I was wondering if it served a purpose, as you can see it is taking up a rather large portion.

Comment: Did you want to add the space of `/dev/sda5` to `/dev/sda6`(_combine_)?

Comment: If possible yes

Answer (score 0):

when you do a fresh install, there are two ways of using custom partitioning. if you simply say install ubuntu and pull the slider, it slices the ntfs partition of your system. the ext4 partition remains unaltered.

the second way of doing it is choosing something else and then in the next step, your partitioning scheme will be visible. you have to select the partition for installing linux and click change in the bottom. choose the type of file system(in your case ext4) and select mount point as / . (/) is the root partition which means your ubuntu is installed there. you can add swap as well as seperate home partiion basing on your intentions and proceed with the installation.

Comment: It mounted the EXT4 partition I made, it didnt touch the NTFS.

Comment: your linux os is installed by shrinking the ntfs partition. your ext4 partition is the extra partition it makes. it is like your c: drive is made by shrinking ntfs and making a new partition. the ext4 partition you are seeing is the d: drive. to get a better picture, install gparted from software center and open it. you will know the complete picture

Comment: It did not install to that partition, I made one before installing, I made it EXT4 and ubuntu mounted that my NTFS was not touched by Ubuntu, and please refer to the link in the comment above for the gparted.

Comment: understood the problem. now your sda6 is c: drive and sda5 is d: drive. you can use it that way. you can create a link to sda5 in your home folder for easy access. you can even bookmark it for quick access from the left. unfortunately, if you want to delete the partition for it to be gulped by your / partition, you will be in trouble. traditionally, partitions can expand towards right side without any trouble. to expand them to the left takes a hell lot of time. you might want to delete the two partitions and create a new big partition and reinstall ubuntu instead.

Comment: i am sorry but you made those decisions for the partitioning scheme and you can't blame ubuntu for that. i can only suggest you that if you want a separate partition for system files and separate partition for your files, try creating two partitions and this time choose to mount one of them as / and the other as /home. to be able to do this, you have to choose something else in the partitioning scheme and assign them manually.

Comment: ...It made a massive empty file, it didnt seperate anything... it only uses one partition how would making another help.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, it's possible to add the space of /dev/sda5 to /dev/sda6.For this, you have to boot from Ubuntu live disk.So that only, you can  able to resize your `/` root partition.

- Boot from Ubuntu live disk and then choose Try Ubuntu option on startup.
- Open gparted from dash.
- Make sure that all the partitions are unmounted and then take a backup of important datas.
- Delete `/dev/sda5` partition.
- Then right-click on `/dev/sda6` partition and choose Resize/Move option.
  Now you can be able to add that free space which was just above to the `/dev/sda6` partition by moving the left arrow to extreme left.